# Why am I getting an unchecked warning?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

I don't understand why I'm getting a warning with the following code:

```
public static boolean isAssignableFrom(Class clazz, Object o) {
    return clazz.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass());
}
```

> Unchecked call to `isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` as a member of raw type `java.lang.Class`

When I use the `isInstance` method instead (which provides identical results from what I understand), I don't get a warning:

```
public static boolean isAssignableFrom(Class clazz, Object o) {
    return clazz.isInstance(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Class` is a generic type, and you aren't telling Java that the `Object` must be an instance of the class. Change

```
public static boolean isAssignableFrom(Class clazz, Object o)
```

to something like

```
public static <C> boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<C> clazz, C o)
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer clarified it. But I think it would be better to leave the `Object o` in place instead of using a type parameter there to be able to check with any object at runtime, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not really, after type erasure the code is the same at runtime (well, there's an implicit cast in my example).

Comment: Let's say I have 3 classes: `Parent`, `Child extends Parent`, `RandomClass`. With the type parameter I could check if the Child is assignable from Parent but I wouldn't be able to do it for RandomClass (`isAssignableFrom(Parent.class, new RandomClass());`)

Comment: Use ? super C in that case.